# is it possible to present a view from the top in a watchOS app like when you swipe to check notifications?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos

**The problem:**

When I present the new screen it always appears from the bottom. This is what I use:

```
presentControllerWithName("Screen1", context: context)
```

I also tried with `pushControllerWithName` and it didn't work. Is it possible to present a view from the top in a watchOS app like when you swipe to check the notifications? If there is, could you tell me how?

**What I want:**

- When I swipe up, a new screen appears from the bottom
- When I swipe down a new screen appears from the top like when you swipe to see the notifications

[image: Notification screen sliding down on an apple watch]